# Why the statement is not equivalent to Conditional proposition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Let $p$ and $q$ be propositions, such that

$p$: You drive over 65 miles per hour

$q$: You get a speeding ticket.

$p\implies q$ means that

> if you drive over 65 miles per hour then you will get a speeding ticket.

Why $p \implies q$ doesn't not equivalent to the following statement:

> If you do not drive over 65 miles per hour, then you will not get a speeding ticket

In natural language, these two statements look the same.

Comment: Because $p \to q$ is **not** equivalent to $\lnot p \to \lnot q$. Check with truth table.

Comment: If you do not drive at 65 miles and you get a speed ticket, the second is false ( True to False is False) while the first is true (False to True is True).

Comment: As per many many posts on this site, you have to consider that the truth-functional connective $\to$ is defined by its truth table and does not express a sort of "causal" link between antecedent and consequent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold on!
You say

> ⟹ means that
>
> > if you drive over 65 miles per hour then you will get a speeding ticket.
>
> Why [isn't] ⟹ equivalent to the following statement:
>
> > If you do not drive over 65 miles per hour, then you will not get a speeding ticket
>
> In natural language, these two statements look the same.

But they are not the same at all. Suppose that the speed limit is 30 miles an hour. Then if you drive over 65 miles per hour then you will get a speeding ticket. But it most certainly doesn't follow that if you do not drive over 65 miles per hour, then you will not get a speeding ticket. Suppose you are caught doing 50 ...

Answer (score 1):

$P \implies Q$ does not mean that $P$ causes $Q$. It means only that at the moment (usually the present), it is false that both $P$ is true and $Q$ is false.  Which moment in time are you talking about in your scenario? The present. Some time in the past. It is impossible to say.

Consider another, less ambiguous example: If it raining then it is cloudy.

$Raining \implies Cloudy$

This does not mean that rain causes cloudiness. It mean only that, at the moment, it is false that it is both raining and not cloudy.

$\neg [Raining \land \neg Cloudy] $